# Transform an n element array into a one column dataframe julia and export a csv file

Tags: arrays, dataframe, julia

I have an 183 elements array that I would like to transform into a one colum dataframe. The array looks `df` like as follows:

```
183-element Array{Array{Float64,2},1}:
 [76.1042 50.0618 … -1.72986 -1.716]   
 [95.2629 84.1194 … -1.7071 -1.69628]  
 [67.404 40.0616 … -6.01294 -5.47409]  
 [66.0865 44.2233 … -4.57463 -4.19918] 
 [45.1631 10.8539 … -1.73326 -1.71894] 
 [98.5844 94.8746 … -4.57998 -4.20398] 
 [50.1387 25.6277 … -1.68957 -1.68109] 
 [45.608 15.6854 … -1.70545 -1.69486]  
 [40.515 7.37472 … -4.01657 -3.70847]  
 [42.3056 11.6015 … -3.12091 -2.9249]  
 [12.3731 -10.2234 … -3.41232 -3.17932]
 [12.6298 -9.61076 … -1.68518 -1.67729]
 [13.0059 -8.60469 … -2.96391 -2.78804]
 ⋮                                     
 [-112.757 -85.998 … -20.0213 -20.019] 
 [-109.492 -84.4215 … -20.013 -20.013] 
 [-109.492 -84.4215 … -20.013 -20.013] 
 [-109.492 -84.4215 … -20.013 -20.013] 
 [-109.492 -84.4215 … -20.013 -20.013] 
 [-109.492 -84.4215 … -20.013 -20.013] 
 [-109.492 -84.4215 … -20.013 -20.013] 
 [-109.492 -84.4215 … -20.013 -20.013] 
 [-109.492 -84.4215 … -20.013 -20.013] 
 [-109.492 -84.4215 … -20.013 -20.013] 
 [-109.492 -84.4215 … -20.013 -20.013] 
 [-113.341 -28.5849 … -20.013 -20.013]
```

The idea is to create a dataframe with one column which is then filled in with the values contained in the 183 element array. Ultimately, I want to export the created dataframe into a csv file.

I have tried something like that but it does not work:

```
df_output=DataFrame(x1=Float64[])  
for i= 1:length(df)
  test=convert(DataFrame, df[i]')
  push!(df_output, test)
end
```

Anyone can help me with that? Thanks.

Comment: Try `df_output = DataFrame(x1=mapreduce(vec, vcat, df))`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Dan Getz, this command line below does the job!

```
df_output = DataFrame(x1=mapreduce(vec, vcat, df))
```